# how do you test simple if else statements with J-unit?

Tags: java, testing, white-box

I have this if-else statement and I want to write a J unit test that will test each individual line to see is correct. Any ideas?

```
public class Testings {

    public static int computeValue(int x, int y, int z) {
        int value = 0;

        if ( x == y ) 
            value = x + 1;
        else if (( x > y) && ( z == 0))
            value = y + 2;
        else
            value = z;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you explain how detailed it should be tested?  - only with single numbers, test clusters, etc

Answer (score 0):

Test your method with the values that cover all cases:

- x == y
- x != y and x > y and z == 0
- x != y and x > y and z != 0
- x != y and x < y and z == 0
- x != y and x < y and z != 0
- x == y and z != 0
- x == y and z == 0

Example:

```
assertEquals(4, Testings.computeValue(3, 3, 10)); // x == y
assertEquals(7, Testings.computeValue(10, 5, 0)); // x != y and x > y and z == 0
assertEquals(1, Testings.computeValue(10, 5, 1)); // x != y and x > y and z != 0
...
```

Also, you should have one *assert* per test method so you can give it a proper name:

```
@Test
public void testXEqualY(){
    int x=3, y=3, z=10;
    assertEquals(4, Testings.computeValue(x, y, z));
}
```

Comment: geez! I just realized this is a few weeks old, probably not useful anymore! Anyhow, here it is :)